# Javascript Com array Component giving me wrong array values

Tags: c#, javascript, html, com

I try to create COM Component for C# method and then try to access this method using javascript.

I have run GACUtil -i and Regasm /Codebase command for create share assembly and also register into Registry successfully. 
This is my C# Method that return an int[] array for this I create an COM Component for this method. 
**nChannelsCount = 15** which is use in for loop

```
[Guid("4794D615-BE51-4a1e-B1BA-453F6E9337C4")]  
  [ComVisible(true)]   
 [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]  
  [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IComOjbect))] 
   public class MyComObject : IComOjbect 
   {
```

[image]
       }

```
   [Guid("4B3AE7D8-FB6A-4558-8A96-BF82B54F329C")] 
   [ComVisible(true)]   
 public interface IComOjbect    
    {       
    [DispId(0x10000009)]    
        int[] GetData(int index);   
     }
```

But when I access this method in javascript it gives me and just count of 15 but I want 5500 count that show in Quick Watch. I dont know how to do this in javascript to achive this code but still i try this javascript code as below

```
<html>   
<head>   
<title>My Com Component</title>  
<object id="myComComponent" name="myComComponent" classid="clsid:4794D615-BE51-4A1E-B1BA-453F6E9337C4">
</object> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">        
function MyComComponent_onload() 
    {              
      try {  
           var nAllData = [];   
           for (var index = 0; index < 15; index++) 
             {

               nAllData.push(myComComponent.GetData(index));  
              } 
            alert(nAllData.length);  
          }             
      catch (err) {             
        alert(err.message);    
       }           
  }   
</script> 
</head>  
<body onload="MyComComponent_onload();" onunload="MyComComponent_onunload();"> 
</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: So, you want your array to be 5500 long in JS but only want to fill its first 15 values?

Comment: @Medinoc He returning 5500 of length array from COM Component developed in c# from above scenario mention in his question.in javscript he Getting array of length (15) instead of (5500) ....alert(nAllData.length) He getting array length 15;

Comment: @Medinoc I want the Quick watch array (that shown in screen shot)into javascript array.

Comment: @RomanR. I didn't get what you means???

Answer (score 1):

`GetData` returns an array. The JavaScript code calls it 15 times, and every time pushes the result onto yet another array, called `nAllData` (the fact that the variable name in JavaScript is the same as in C# is irrelevant - they are unrelated). As a result, you have an array of 15 elements, where each of those elements is in turn an array (presumably of 5500 elements - whatever `GetData` returns).

The loop within `GetData` implementation is pointless - the function returns on the very first  iteration through that loop. It's not clear what you were trying to achieve there.

Finally, I don't believe JavaScript can directly consume safearrays (which is how I believe the return value of `GetData` ends up being represented by COM interop). Try this:

```
var data = new VBArray(myComComponent.GetData(index)).toArray();
alert(data.length);
nAllData.push(data);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives me error like "VBArray: argument is not a VBArray object."

Comment: What happens if you simply do `var data = myComComponent.GetData(index);`? I must admit I'm not really familiar with .NET COM interop, I'm not sure what a .NET array would look like on COM side of things.

Comment: it iterate the loop for 15 times but not gave me nDataArray as shown in quick watch

Comment: What **does** it give you? What's in `data` right after `GetData` call? What happens with `alert(data.length)`?

Comment: it gives me only count up to 15. And as per your code snippets happens with alert(data.length) is not execute it gives me an above error that i mention in my first comment."VBArray: argument is not a VBArray object."

Comment: Of course `nAllData.length` is 15 - you are pushing onto it exactly 15 times. What happens if you do `var data = myComComponent.GetData(index); alert(data.length);` inside the loop?

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply right now I am way from my PC I'll reply to you soon....